# href{} in longtable{} simply printed verbatim

Tags: hyperref, longtable, sv-classes

When using href{} inside a longtable, its simply printed out in a verbatim way. How can I make it behave like expected (produce a working link in the pdf file that shows the href label?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
%
\usepackage{type1cm}         

\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                             % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{longtable}

% define detailled toc
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

% longtable
\usepackage{longtable,lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
% \usepackage{multirow,multicol}


\begin{document}


\chapter{Links}
\label{cha:tasks} % Always give a unique label
% use \chaptermark{}
% to alter or adjust the chapter heading in the running head

\section*{Tabular Depiction }
\label{sec:tabular-depiction}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{longtable}{ll}
\caption{Caption} \\hline
Task & URI \\hline\hline\endfirsthead
\caption{Caption (cont.)}  \Task & URI \\hline\endhead
\hline
 & www.uri.org \\hline\endfoot
\hline
Web Site  & www.uri.org \\hline\endlastfoot

doors & href{http://code.org/wiki/doors}{http://code.org/wiki/doors} \game & href{http://code.org/wiki/game}{http://code.org/game} \Solve & href{http://code.org/wiki/Solve}{http://code.org/wiki/Solve} \

\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: shouldn't you enter `\href{http://code.org/wiki/doors}{http://code.org/wiki/doors}` instead of `href{http://code.org/wiki/doors}{http://code.org/wiki/doors}`. Note the missing backslash in your `href` link.

Comment: just wondering any reason to include `longtable` package twice?

Comment: Oh yes, I should probably enter the backslash ... *sigh* (no, longtable appears 2 times only by accident). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is `\href` but you are using `href` (the backslash is missing):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{type1cm}         
\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                             % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{longtable}% longtable

% define detailled toc
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
% \usepackage{multirow,multicol}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Links}
\label{cha:tasks} % Always give a unique label
% use \chaptermark{}
% to alter or adjust the chapter heading in the running head

\section*{Tabular Depiction }
\label{sec:tabular-depiction}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{ll}
\caption{Caption} \\
\hline
Task & URI \\
\hline\hline\endfirsthead
\caption{Caption (cont.)}  \\
Task & URI \\
\hline\endhead
\hline
 & www.uri.org \\
\hline\endfoot
\hline
Web Site  & www.uri.org \\
\hline
\endlastfoot
doors & \href{http://code.org/wiki/doors}{http://code.org/wiki/doors} \\
game & \href{http://code.org/wiki/game}{http://code.org/game} \\
Solve & \href{http://code.org/wiki/Solve}{http://code.org/wiki/Solve} \\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `article` instead of `svmono` since I don't have the later class. You were loading twice the `longtable` package, so I suppressed one of them; also I moved `hyperref` to be the last package loaded (this is usually recommended except for some packages).

Comment: Thanks, sometimes one is blind for the apparently obvious.

Comment: @user17106 You're welcome! I updated my answer with two remarks.